# [SwiftUI]how to find a specified element in view struct by identifier

Tags: recursion, swiftui, view, identifier

For example, how to find the following Text with identifier "id_d".

```
  struct a : View {
  var body : some View {
     VStack {
         HStack {
              Text("b")
             Image(....)
         }
        HStack {
             ....
             TextField(...)
             Text("d").accessibleIdentifier("id_d")
        }
     }
  }  

}
```

**Backgound:**
I have a requirement that implementing a coach marks (or walk through) in existing project written in swiftui. in which there are server View files, so I just want to find a common way to achieve this function instead of adding modifiers with every element. in common process, i need to find target by identifier in runtime, and get the position of it, and add coach marks using other view.

Comment: What you want to achieve by this?

Comment: @Carsten  thanks for responding, i added background for My question. pls refer to that.

Comment: AFAIK modifying the view stack programmatically is not intended for SwiftUI. If you want to achieve something like that there are multiple ways to achieve it e.g. StateObject, ObservedObject, EnvironmentObject, Notification